# Using a global variable versus passing a variable around while writing a recursive algorithm

Tags: java, recursion

I have a method to flatten a Binary search tree. I have two approaches for it:

• Using a variable and passing it around

```
import java.util.*;

public class BST {

private Node root;

private class Node {
    private int val;             // associated data
    private Node left, right;  // left and right subtree

    public Node(int val) {
        this.val = val;

    }
}   

public ArrayList<Integer> flattenTree(){

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    flattenTree(root, list);

    return list;
}

public void flattenTree(Node node, ArrayList<Integer> list)
{

    if (node == null)
        return;

    flattenTree(node.left, list);
    list.add(node.val);
    flattenTree(node.right, list);

}    

public static void main(String[] args) {

    BST bst = new BST();

    bst.add(5);
    bst.add(1);
    bst.add(0);
    bst.add(3);

    System.out.println(bst.flattenTree());

}

}
```

• Using a class variable:

```
import java.util.*;

public class BST {

private Node root;

ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();    

private class Node {
    private int val;             // associated data
    private Node left, right;  // left and right subtree

    public Node(int val) {
        this.val = val;

    }
}   

public ArrayList<Integer> flattenTree(){

    flattenTree(root);

    return list;
}

public void flattenTree(Node node)
{

    if (node == null)
        return;

    flattenTree(node.left);
    list.add(node.val);
    flattenTree(node.right);

}    

public static void main(String[] args) {

    BST bst = new BST();

    bst.add(5);
    bst.add(3);
    bst.add(1);
    bst.add(0);
    bst.add(3);
    bst.add(3);

    bst.printInorder();
    System.out.println(bst.flattenTree());

}
```

}

In both cases I get:

```
sgupta$ java BST
[0, 1, 3, 5]
```

I'm a beginner to java (high school) and wondering what the pros and cons of each approach are.

The only one I can think of is that approach #2 has less messy code by not having to pass the list around.

Answer (score 3):

To add to @caskey's points, I'd like to point out two other major advantages of the first version of the code.

First, the code that accepts an explicit list is *harder to use incorrectly*. If you call the second version of the code, you need to

- make sure no one else is calling the method in a parallel thread,
- make sure that the list variable has been initialized,
- make sure that the list doesn't already contain anything else, and
- remember to read off the list when you're done with it.

If you forget to do any of these, your program will not behave as expected, but you won't get any compiler errors indicating this. This makes the code harder to use correctly and increases the chances that you'll get more bugs in your program.

Second, the first version *has an easier description*. The first version of the code can be described as "populate the given list with an inorder traversal of the tree." The second version is "appends to the existing contents of the list `list` an inorder traversal of the tree." It's harder to describe what this second one does, so the burden on the documentation is greater. Plus, it's harder for programmers reading the code for the first time to understand what it does.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

The disadvantage, in general, to global variables is twofold.

1) you have only one global variable and so two copies of your code can't run at the same time (i.e., multiple threads).

2) The global variable can be modified in other places which your code might not expect.

Your first answer is the better engineered solution.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. From what I read, it seems that a 'global variable' is one that is Class specific or 'static'. In my case, it is not a static variable, does that still come under a global var?

Comment: static variables can be considered global as there exists only one instance of the variable no matter how many times the class is instantiated.  Class variables have a different one in each instance of the class.  Regardless, passing the list in to the function is more correct than either of those because you could still have two callers in the one function.

Answer (score 0):

Good questions to ask:

- Does the class have state it needs to hold onto?
- If so, what is the state (i.e. the fields)?
- Can you avoid state by passing arguments in method calls, which makes for easier to test code.